# Socket does not work from an external network (PHP+JS+Apache+SSL+Linux)

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

Can't connect to socket from external network. From LAN all works well. What I forgot? Can't find tips on the internet :(

My PHP Server connection:

```
    $host = 'external_ip'; //also tried: 0.0.0.0, local_ip, domain
    $port = 9000;
    $path = '/etc/ssl/private/domain.com/';
    $transport = 'tlsv1.3';
    $ssl = ['ssl' => [
        'local_cert'  => $path . 'domain.com.cer',
        'local_pk'    => $path . 'domain.com.key',
        'disable_compression' => true,
        'verify_peer'         => false,
        'ssltransport' => $transport
    ]];
    $ssl_context = stream_context_create($ssl);
    $server = stream_socket_server($transport . '://' . $host . ':' . $port, $errno, $errstr, STREAM_SERVER_BIND | STREAM_SERVER_LISTEN, $ssl_context);
    
    ....
```

JS:

```
var wsUri = "wss://domain.com:9000/server.php";
websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
```

LAN - works well

external network - not (Chrome console: "WebSocket connection to 'wss://domain.com:9000/server.php' failed:")

Best regards
Maciej

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right protocol? Usually you want `https://example.com/blah`, with the websocket then negotiating the upgrade to the websocket protocol with your server instead.

Comment: Are connections to that port allowed by the firewall from external networks?

Comment: Mike: I have on server OpenSSL 1.1.1d => TLS 1.3.

Comment: Christopher: I think problem is like You suggest - lack handshake on external connection (in Chrome console looks like timeout). I tested with open 9000 port tcp/udp - still problem.